# Python automatically changing its value - Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.8

Let's say I have 3 files -

1. main.py
2. CommunicationsHandler.py
3. main_canvas.py

Contents of `main.py`

```
# Showing only main part
from CommunicationsHandler import CommunicationsHandler

def replace_window(event):
    root.geometry('+0+0')

l.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', replace_window)
CommunicationsHandler.root = root

import main_canvas
from main_canvas import *

# root = CommunicationsHandler.root
```

Contents of `main_canvas.py`

```
# Showing only main part
from CommunicationsHandler import CommunicationsHandler

# I had to keep this name to root as I created main.py later
root = tk.Toplevel(CommunicationsHandler.root)
CommunicationsHandler.child = root
```

Contents of `CommunicationsHandler`

```
# Showing only main part
class CommunicationsHandler:
    root = None
    child = None
```

Now when `<ButtonRelease-1>` binding is fired in `main.py`, it doesn't change the geometry of GUI of `main.py` rather it changes the GUI of `main_canvas.py` how is this possible? I solved the problem by uncommenting the last line of `main.py` but still is it automatically changing its root or what?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] which can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is because after `from main_canvas import *` `root` inside `main.py` will be override by `root` inside `main_canvas`.  You can remove the line `from main_canvas import *` and see the difference.

Comment: Hi @acw1668 You are AWESOME! Thanks a lot! I don't know why I didn't think of that. If you would like, please post this comment as the answer so I can put it up as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because after executing the following line:

```
from main_canvas import *
```

the `root` inside `main.py` will be override by `root` inside `main_canvas` module.

If you remove that line from `main.py`, you will see the difference.

It is one of the reason why `from xxx import *` is not recommended.